# Module Promise: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

i just searched for my problems around in the stackoverflow's discussions but nothings similar with my issued. So, in this case, i just want to update my collection and then use the 'Promise' module instead use the callbacks / anonymous functions as normally i did. but the error comes up when I execute the js's application in cmd.

Here my simple code:

```js
var Promise = require('promise'); // use the 'promise' module
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';

    MongoClient.connect(url)
     .then(function(err, db) {
         db.collection('Employee').updateOne({
             "EmployeeName": "Jeffrey"
         }, {
             $set: {
                 "EmployeeName": "Jeffrey Scurgs"
             }
         });
     });
```

and the error results when i executed the code in cmd:

> (node:8600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'collection' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\DELL\guru99\5_Promise\app_promise.js:7:9
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) (node:8600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:8600) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

so, is there any wrong code in my code above?

thanks for helping... 
*sorry for my bad english*

Comment: `db` is undefined so check the content of `err`

Comment: Have you checked your err object to see if there might be an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct but you a missed one thing.

When you don't provide callback parameters mongo ORM return a promise. Here is the corrected code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function(db) { // <- db is first argument
        db.collection('Employee').updateOne({
            "EmployeeName": "Jeffrey"
        }, {
            $set: {
                "EmployeeName": "Jeffrey Scurgs"
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {})
```

Comment: so.. what if I nested the Promise like   **MongoClient.connect(url)

.then(function(db) {
 db.collection('Employee').insertOne({
  Employeeid: 4,
  EmployeeName: "NewEmployee"
 })

 .then(function(db1) {

  db1.collection('Employee').insertOne({
   Employeeid: 5,
   EmployeeName: "NewEmployee1"
  });
 });
});**    should I added the catch twice?

Comment: Hi..!! Is your query resolved about multiple return promises ?

Comment: Exactly man... helping by Bergi in comment below... thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

The `db` variable can only be undefined if there was an error connecting to the database.

You need to check and fix any error shown. You can also share the error

```js
var Promise = require('promise'); // use the 'promise' module
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';

    MongoClient.connect(url)
     .then(function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
              return throw err; // Check the error
            }
         db.collection('Employee').updateOne({
             "EmployeeName": "Jeffrey"
         }, {
             $set: {
                 "EmployeeName": "Jeffrey Scurgs"
             }
         });
     });
```